# inserting joomla 1.5 user to Mysql gives a wrong password

Tags: php, joomla

I am making a custom joomla account creation script that generates a randon password as well that is mailed tp the user. the account is created but the password is always not working.

I already capture user,email, etc.

```
$password = rand(1000,99999);
 $password2  = md5($password);
$query = "INSERT INTO jos_users          (username,email,name,usertype,sendEmail,gid,params,registerDate,password) 
VALUES (' $username','$email','$name','Registered','1','18','admin_language=
 language=
 editor=
helpsite=
timezone=0',NOW(),'$password2')";   
    $result = mysql_query($query);
     $uid=mysql_insert_id();
```

ETC.................... ETC

I have tried these variations

```
  sha1($_POST['pword']);
```

and

```
 $password = rand(1000,9999);
 $salt = md5(rand(1000,9999));
 $password2 = md5($password.$salt).":".$salt;
```

STILL WHEN I SEND USER $password it is wrong and cant login.
could i be missing something.

```
  /////////////////////////////full script just in case///////////////////////////////

  $password = rand(1000,99999);
  $password2  = md5($password);
 die($password2);
 $query = "INSERT INTO jos_users     (username,email,name,usertype,sendEmail,gid,params,registerDate,password) 
 VALUES (' $username','$email','$name','Registered','1','18','admin_language=
language=
editor=
helpsite=
timezone=0',NOW(),'$password2')";   
    $result = mysql_query($query);
     $uid=mysql_insert_id();


    $query = "INSERT INTO #__spcClient (clientID,GSM,StartingUnits,Units) VALUES ('$uid','$GSM','$units','$units')";    
    $myfunctions->dbquery($query);

    $query = "INSERT INTO jos_core_acl_aro (section_value,value,name) VALUES ('users','$uid','$name')";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
     $uid2=mysql_insert_id();
    //$rowcount = $db->getAffectedRows($result);
    $query = "INSERT INTO jos_core_acl_groups_aro_map (group_id,aro_id) VALUES ('18','".$uid2."')";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////

Comment: Joomla passwords are salted as well as using the md5 method

Comment: exactly my point, im stuck i have salted, md5vd and sha1'ned in vain, its that method that defeating me, hope i come up with the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you've tried all these variations but for future reference in Joomla! you can look at `/libraries/joomla/user/` in particular you may want to look at `helper.php` which includes the method `getCryptedPassword()`. The default encryption ('md5-hex') switches to this code:

```
case 'md5-hex' :
default :
    $encrypted = ($salt) ? md5($plaintext.$salt) : md5($plaintext);
    return ($show_encrypt) ? '{MD5}'.$encrypted : $encrypted;
```

It would also be worth looking at the `bind()` method in `user.php` which binds the submitted data and creates the password array (which contains the salt and encrypted password).

```
$array['password'] = $crypt.':'.$salt;
```

Answer (score 0):

you got me rolling in the right direction. thanks. I think joomla has a bug. I performed a db update after the insert and it work. I reset the pwd to itself!

```
           '$query  = 'UPDATE #__users'
            . ' SET password = '.$db->Quote($password)
            . ' , activation = ""'
            . ' WHERE id = '.(int) $id
            . ' AND block = 0';

    $db->setQuery($query);

    // Save the password
    $db->query();'
```